# How to read an SMS message from inbox using j2me (midp2.0)?

Tags: java, java-me, sms, midp-2.0, inbox

I want to access the inbox message text from j2me application. I have no idea about accessing inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve this with j2me. I already discussed in Nokia forum. See [this link](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?205226-Read-SMS&p=768404&highlight=#post768404).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, But you can not directly access the In-Box using J2ME Code, You need a .Jar file called `APIBridge.jar`

This .Jar file allows you to interact with the lowerlever api. As the name implies it is a Bridge between J2ME API and Native OS API.

Please visit this [link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/J2ME_API_Bridge_Interface) for more information.