# how do I access mobile inbox, call log, photo gallery using j2me APIBridge?

Tags: java, api, java-me, nokia

I was searching for the method or some kind of examples, by which i can access my mobile phone call logs or message inbox. But, I failed to find, because in all blogs and even in this site (Stack Overflow), everyone saying that, it can't be possible. Today, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793696/reading-sms-from-inbox-in-j2me), which increase my hope, which I wanted to do. As Lucifer said, using [APIBridge](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Tools_and_downloads/Other/APIBridge/) we can achieve this.

Then, I found [this example](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/File:J2MEBridgeExamples.zip), in which accessing call logs and photo gallery has been explained. But, when i was trying to use this example on my phone, then it tried to access the internet. I checked the code, but didn't find any URL inside it. Can anyone help me to understand or how can I use the this example for my mobile phone?

I am developing on Nokia 6700 Classic S40 Series Phone.

Comment: if your targeted device is s40 then it is not possible to read inbox or call log.

Comment: @Mihir what would be alternative of APIBridge.jar for reading inbox for s40 series mobile..?

Comment: I have updated my answer @coders_zone, have you read it ?

Comment: yes i do. so, the conclusion is, there is no way to access inbox in s40 mobile. am i right.. ??

Comment: yes you are right. there is no way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**APIBridge** Jar is based on Symbian Operating System Phones, mostly S60 Series. So in your case you can not read access Inbox,call logs, photo gallery using `APIBridge.jar`.

I read the details here for [API Bridge Interface](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/J2ME_API_Bridge_Interface). It says that. The APIBridge is a Symbian server that exposes an HTTP interface for communication between the server and its clients. The APIBridge can be used by making an http call to the local host port that the APIBridge listens to. The following architecture diagram explains the different parts of the system:

[image]

- **Access Layer J2ME API :**

  - The J2ME API provides java applications with a function-based interface to the services of the APIBridge. It performs the following activities:
    Authentication with the Bridge
  - HTTP requests to the APIBridge from the function calls, abstracting this complexity from the application developer;
- **Framework Layer APIBridge Server :**

  - The APIBridge Server is responsible for authenticating clients, receiving requests, routing requests to the appropriate APIBridge plug-in for execution, and returning the results.
- **ECOM Plug-ins Layer Plug-ins :**

  - Plug-ins are responsible for analyzing the parameters in the request, calling the appropriate Symbian APIs to execute it, and creating the HTTP response.

So, from the above description it you can see that it uses HTTP Connection in APIBridge Interface, this is the reason that your application is trying to access the Internet Connection.

Comment: So, which means, to access my call logs it will access the internet. ??

Comment: yes, because in background APIBridge.jar file accesses the Internet Connection

Comment: but, it creating a loop, for asking the permission for accessing the internet. I mean it asking the permission again and again in my mobile. How can i remove this...?? On the other hand, is it true that, this APIBridge.jar can not be used for the s40 series mobile.. ??

Comment: for permission, you need to sign your application to avoid those messages. I haven't use APIBridge Jar file on s40, so can't say, give me 30 minutes, i will check and confirm it back to you. you can come to my chat room for instant conversion.

Comment: you cannot use Apibridge for s40. It is purely made for Symbian device only.

Comment: @Mihir any library or api available for s40 series, by which i can read inbox.