# listening to sms, which is sent without any port number in j2me app

Tags: java, java-me

I have a SMS Sender & Receiver MIDlet with MessageConnection created in Client mode for sending SMS to a particular destination on a particular port. This destination is sending back an ACK SMS without any port number set, to my device inbox. My MIDLet is listening on a same port number used for sending SMS. Problem is MIDlet is unable to listen & process this SMS. The message always goes & sits in the device inbox. Is there any way to listen to SMS without any port number? or route the SMS to the MIDlet?

Comment: Pratik you can check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10645996/996493), it is possible in s60 series devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible to receive SMS on the standard port with JavaME.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in S60 Series device.