# How can I receive incoming sms in JavaME?

Tags: java-me, sms, wma

I'm developing an application in javaME and I'm trying to receive incoming sms but there is a way to catch them that is working only with ports and there must be two applications but I want to send sms in a phone without using javame application to other phone that hasn't javame application.

I want to receive incoming sms without using port. How can I do this, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java ME, You can't read SMS from inbox. There is a way to read SMS from Inbox, but it is for symbian phone like S60 series ( Nokia E72,E5 ) etc only.

In S60 series phone using [API Bridge](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Tools_and_downloads/Other/APIBridge/) jar file, you can achieve your requirement. Please check out http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Tools_and_downloads/Other/APIBridge/ page for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I wonder something. If I use this API Bridge jar file for S60 can I install and use the application to all over java phones? For example, application will work on nokia s60 devices but will it work on samsung star? In fact, how can implement this function in java telephones like Samsung star or etc.

Comment: sorry, you can use if only if and if the ApiBridge.jar is there, because as the name Bridge says, it is bridge between your Java ME code and Symbian Operating system.

Comment: And sorry, I have a problem. I rode the articles about apibridges on developer.nokia but I didn't find anything about reading inbox?

Comment: No Problem, please check my [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10645996/996493)

Comment: I checked it. By the way, i wrote a program to try this apibridge but i couldn't get calllog. If you want i can send to my source code, can you check it?

Comment: do one thing, ask it in new question, so others can also see it and write answers if they know about it